# Muenchian grouping and /*

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0. When used in apply-templates it works for the first `<level>` element then fails to output for further `<level>` elements.

Sample input XML: note that the siblings of `<areas>` can be variable

```
 <levels>
   <level>
     <areas>      
       <p1>A</p1>
       <p1>B</p1>
       <p2>C</p2>
     </areas>      
   </level>
   <level>
     <areas>
       <p3>C</p4>
       <p3>D</p3>
       <p4>E</p4>      
     </areas>
   </level>
 </levels>
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="names" match="*/areas/*" use="local-name(.)" />

<xsl:template match="/levels/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./areas/*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('names', local-name(.)))]" mode="A" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="A">
  <xsl:variable name="category" select="local-name(.)" />
  <xsl:element name="{$category}">
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired output:

```
<p1>
<p2>
<p3>
<p4>
```

Output returned:

```
<p1>
<p2>
```

Any ideas on why it ignores the second `<level>` element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change

```
<xsl:template match="/levels/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./areas/*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('names', local-name(.)))]" mode="A" />
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/levels">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="level/areas/*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('names', local-name(.)))]" mode="A" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried it in a larger implementation I am working on and still produced no output. When I remove the generate-id code both levels are outputed [although it includes the duplicates I do not want included].

Comment: Issue fixed. Changing the key to use="generate-id(child::*[1])" and then applying the same to the apply-template [generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('names', generate-id(child::*[1])))] picks up the other elements.

Comment: @user3427584 Please accept this answer (mark the tick on the left) if it was helpful to you.